# Ctrl+L won't clear Python3.3 terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, readline

I installed Python3.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 x86 on VirtualBox, from source:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3
make && sudo make install
```

I can launch python3.3 successfully and the problem starts from there.

1. CTRL+L doesn't clear the python console/terminal, It just displays `^L^L`
2. even the up key doesn't show the previous command entered, instead I get `[[^A` when I press the up key.

But if I install python3.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 following the same procedure, everything works fine. 
If I install python from `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes` (Ubuntu 12.04 x86 or x64), it works perfectly but installs Python3.3 minimal.

Please tell me where I am making a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [`libreadline-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libreadline-dev) for readline support to work.

Once installed, re-compile Python.

You may be missing other dependencies used by other extensions. You may want to install:

```
libncursesw5-dev
libssl-dev
libgdbm-dev
libsqlite3-dev
tk-dev
```

as well to take full advantage of Python's extension modules.

Comment: Thanks Martijn,

The solution works perfectly for the problem asked earlier.

But again help(print) works with python 3.3m (deadsnake) but not in the python installed from source, with all the dependencies suggested.